# Connect to separate database using $wpdb and authenticate user

Tags: wpdb

Have a couple questions. Just to get everyone up to date:

- I had created a new file wp-custom-config.php
- Use define `define( 'NEW_HOST', host name);` and other details.
- And add code for DB connect like below

  `$newdb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);`

  `$newdb->show_errors();`
- Included this file in wp-config.php file.

So the wp-customer-config.php looks like:

```
$DB_NAME_EXT = 'database';

/** database username */
/*define('DB_USER_EXT', 'username');*/
$DB_USER_EXT = 'username';

/** database password */
/*define('DB_PASSWORD_EXT', 'password');*/
$DB_PASSWORD_EXT = 'password';

/** database hostname */
/*define('DB_HOST_EXT', 'host');*/
$DB_HOST_EXT = 'host';

global $newdb;
$newdb = new wpdb($DB_NAME_EXT, $DB_USER_EXT, $DB_PASSWORD_EXT, $DB_HOST_EXT );
$newdb->show_errors();
```

Like I mention before, I have included it or should I say required it in the wp-config.php at the bottom after `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php')` and looks like...

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'external-config.php');
```

---

FIRST QUESTION: - I read that you can use `$newdb` in any file any where. How would you do that? Can I see examples?

SECOND QUESTION: I want to use the `$newdb` for the login page. So instead of using the `$wpdb`, I want to use `$newdb` to pick and check username and password. How would I do that? Would I need to make a custom login page or can I go into the code and switched databases around? Whats the best practice?